# Toast message does not show up when I call it from app.components.ts

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic5, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm trying to display toast message when the app receives FCM push notifications while the app in foreground but the toast message does not show up, I placed `alert(data.message)` and the alert show up without issue but toast messages does not. BTW the toast message works fine in other pages in the app but not in app.components.ts

```
initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {

     this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data);
       if (data.wasTapped) 
       {
        ....
        ...
       } else {
         alert(data.message);

         this.presentToast(data.message);
       }
      });      

      // refresh the FCM token
      this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(async token => {
       console.log(token);
      ....
      ...
      });

    });
 }

 async presentToast(msg) {
   const toast = await this.toast.create({
      message: msg,
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'top'
   });
   await toast.present();
 }
```

Comment: any error are you check console.log??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async` functions return promises and should return something to the calling function

```
...
this.presentToast(data.message);
...
```

does neither

so you have 2 options:

1. modify the `presentToast` function like so:

   ```
     presentToast(msg) {
      const toast = this.toast.create({
      message: msg,
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'top'
   });
    toast.present();
   ```

   }
2. consume the returned promise and present the toast function in the calling function

```
    ...
    initializeApp() {
    ...
       this.presentToast(data.message).then(data => 
           console.log('toast displayed')).catch(error => 
           console.log(error));
    ...
    
    async presentToast(msg) {
     this.toast.create({
    message: msg,
    duration: 3000,
     position: 'top'
    });
     return await toast.present();
    }
```

Comment: I did the first option and still not showing up.

Comment: The second option worked for me...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove '*await*' and just call `toast.present()`.

Comment: Why? `await` will just consume the promise return.

Comment: I removed await but still not showing up.